# Union of data that cannot be joined

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Goal: write a query that can bring back all the users of a company, and the company's primary user.

I have funky situation where there is login structure that my company has set in place. The tables look like so:

```
User

  int        int          bit
UserId | CompanyId | IsPrimaryUser |

UserLoginBridge

  int      int
UserId | LoginId

Login

 int
LoginId | CompanyId | ...
```

Obviously the relationships here are much less than optimal. But this is what I have to work with. My issue is that users can be assigned to many Companies .. so there is a 1:M relationship between  User and Login that is expressed by UserLoginBridge.

There is also a Primary User ... indicated by the present of a 1 in the IsPrimaryUser col. In addition, the primary user is never placed into the UserLoginBridge but he has a Login entry .... So the catch is .. I cannot join my way to a primary user.

Any thoughts?

```
Ideal DataSet

UserId | IsPrimaryUser | CompanyId | LoginId
```

Comment: So what would your ideal result set look like?

Comment: How do you know the LoginId for the PrimaryUser if he doesn't exist in UserLoginBridge?

Comment: @Joe Stefannelli Because the earliest appearance of a login entry with the specified companyid is the primary login id ... yay Lolz.

Comment: @Joe stefannelli this configuration only allows me to either target the primary user as a loginId or as a User ... I have no way as of yet to combine them into a single dataset

Comment: in reference to your "inject the data" question - how do you know what data to inject if there's no referential link for the PrimaryUser rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain the method to my madness.

The subquery "q" in the first SELECT finds minimum login ID for each company. Those should be the logins for the primary user, one per company. I can then join primary users to that subquery on CompanyId.

The second select for regular users should need no explanation.

This could be written without the UNION using COALESCE for CompanyId and LoginId, but I think this version is a little easier to read and understand.

```
/* Primary User */
SELECT u.UserId, u.IsPrimaryUser, q.CompanyId, q.LoginId
    FROM User u
        INNER JOIN (SELECT l.CompanyId, MIN(l.LoginId)
                        FROM login l
                        GROUP BY l.CompanyId) q
            ON u.CompanyId = q.CompanyId
    WHERE u.IsPrimaryUser = 1
UNION ALL
/* Regular Users */
SELECT u.UserId, u.IsPrimaryUser, l.CompanyId, l.LoginId
    FROM User u
        INNER JOIN UserLoginBridge ulb
            ON u.UserId = ulb.UserId
        INNER JOIN Login l
            ON ulb.LoginId = l.LoginId
    WHERE u.IsPrimaryUser = 0
```

Comment: This is definitely on track with what I have been trying. I apologize .. I lied about the fact that I know by there being the presence of NULLS in the User and UserLoginBridge tables ... there is still the opportunity for other entries to exist under those conditions. Another thing to note is that a User may not be assigned to a login entry.

Comment: I do know by default that the lowest login id for a specified companyId is the primary user login id

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much ... I was on to this for a while but couldn't get it right. It's funny ... once you have to start verbalizing the relationships the answer starts to form right there writing the question cause I was trying to modify yours to what it looks like now. =D Cheers!